# Getting error "too few arguments" in like query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am looking to get records for the search keyword,
`$keyword` contains the value for search.

Here is the query:

```
$qry = sprintf("select name from Objects where name like '%$keyword%'");
```

Error:

```
sprintf(): Too few arguments in <b>C:\xampp\ht...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sprintf()` takes wildcards that start with `%`.  Why are you using it in this case anyway, as opposed to:

```
$qry = "select name from Objects where name like '%$keyword%'";
```

Or, better yet, using parameterized queries.

Comment: Wow, okay that one was really fast!

Comment: @Payam I think the fastest is saw from Gordon Linoff was in 11sec answered or so :D